# Is there a way to not send API key with the request everytime in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api

I have made an API key for certain users like this :

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var createUniqueId = function() {
    return 'User:' + uuid.v4();
};
```

Yet at this level I request the API key in the header with each request and I fear this might not be the best practice. Is there a way to authenticate the user for certain amount of time and if the time expires the API key is request again or should I stick with asking for API key with each query.

Comment: Why would it be a bad practice?

Comment: Looks like the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. If you have a stateless request-response backend you need to stick to sending API key with the each query.

Comment: How would you plan to authenticate/authorize the user for any given request if they don't provide their key?  Are you instead looking to maintain their authentication server-side in something like session state?  For an API I'd argue *that* to be "bad practice".  But more to the point, it would require that the client provide a session cookie on every request, so nothing is gained.

Answer (score 1):

To implement authentication for a certain amount of time and avoid requesting the API key with each query, you can consider using [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction). JWT is are a popular method for authentication and can provide a stateless authentication mechanism.

Here's a high-level overview of how you can implement JWT-based authentication:

- **User Authentication:**

> When a user logs in or authenticates, generate a JWT on the server-side and include the user's unique identifier in the payload of the token.
> Sign the token using a secret key known only to the server.

- **Token Expiration:**

> Include an expiration time (exp) claim in the JWT payload, indicating the time when the token should expire.
> When generating the token, set an appropriate expiration time based on your requirements.

- **Token Storage:**

> After generating the token, store it on the client-side (e.g., in local storage or a cookie).
> The client will include the JWT in the header of each subsequent API request.

- **Token Verification:**

> On the server-side, verify the JWT in each API request's header.
> Ensure the token's signature is valid using the secret key.
> Check the expiration time to see if the token has expired.

- **Token Refresh:**

> If the token has expired, the server can respond with an appropriate error status code (e.g., 401 Unauthorized).
> The client-side application can handle this error and prompt the user to re-authenticate.

Upon re-authentication, the server will generate a new JWT, and the client will update the stored token.
By using JWTs with an expiration time, you can authenticate the user for a certain period and avoid requesting the API key with each query. However, note that the client will still need to send the JWT in the header for each API request within the token's valid lifespan.

[Securing Node.js RESTful APIs with JSON Web Tokens](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52/)